# Does VS 2010 do bounds check on malloc or new memory allocation?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, bounds

Using VS 2010.  Have already analyzed for memory leakage.  Now I want to know if during execution the compiled code is doing bounds checking.  I am reasonably certain that this happens for vectors and arrays created in C++;  what I do not know is whether bounds checking extends to objects created either by a call to **malloc** or by using the **new** keyword.  If VS does *not* do bounds checking for such a case, is there a 3rd party facility that does do it?

Answer (score 2):

The debug CRT heap will allocate an "overrun buffer" around the new block of memory and check the buffer for an expected value (0xFD) when the block is freed.  When the overrun buffer contains values other than what is expected, you'll get a CRT runtime check failure dialog.  This will catch overrun writes but not reads.  Unfortunately, there's no good way of catching out of bounds reads, provided your process has access to the page being read.

See [Memory Management and the Debug Heap](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bebs9zyz%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) and [_CrtSetDbgFlag](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5at7yxcs%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

Arrays are *not* bounds checked by default in C++, regardless of whether they are statically or dynamically allocated. I used to use [BoundsChecker](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BoundsChecker) for this with Visual C++. On Linux there is also valgrind, which is nice.